Preserving offsets in Kafka migrations with MirrorMaker
When migrating kafka clusters with MirrorMaker, I've found that offsets are not preserved. That is a problem because it means after the migration some stateful services that I have won't be able to resume their processing. Examples of such services are Kafka Streams apps or Flink jobs. I guess for those services I need to drop the part of the state containing the offsets and rely on the consumer group offsets instead. It would be just much simpler if MirrorMaker automatically handled everything / made a perfect (identical) clone of the topics in the first place but that seems unfeasible.

MirrorMaker2 should be preserving offsets. MirrorMaker 1 shouldn't be used anymore. Please show your configs

It still appears that offsets will differ in general based on the official FAQ here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/hdinsight/kafka/kafka-mirrormaker-2-0-guide.md#frequently-asked-questions...

BTW Alternative (Kafka-like) brokers already handle that, see, e.g., https://docs.warpstream.com/warpstream/byoc/orbit.

I'm not sure the Azure docs are a source of truth. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#georeplication Also, offsets should  not (can't?) match. For example, I have a topic that I start mirroring at offset 2000 (all older events have been deleted from retention). On the destination side, it simply wont start at 2000 for a brand new topic. Syncing of record timestamps is a better way to handle this

Yeah, regardless the inherent technical reasons, that poses a challenge for migrating stateful workloads, which need to be analyzed in a one-by-one basis. For example, for Flink in particular you could do something as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78753229/kafka-migration-with-mm2-and-flink-how-to-handle-offset-changes-and-savepoints. Even if you only had Flink apps affected, that would be painful, let alone if you have other types of stateful workloads (Spark, Kafka Streams, Beam...).

Agreed, though Kafka Streams is the only standout application there since the others don't have to use kafka to store state. Flink and Spark have remote checkpoint files and can write to multiple kafka clusters
